# Выборка не повторяющихся значений из одной таблицы чередующихся столбцов

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть одна таблица - в ней есть поля которые чередуются, т.е. допустим
id, A, B, и другие поля

```
id A  B
1  17  16 ...
2  17  14 ...
3  16  17 ...
4  16  14 ...
5  14  17 ...
6  14  16 ....
```

Как получить только те записи где комбинация столбцов А и В уникальна (не повторяется)?

```
т.е. ИД 1, 2, 4, 6 ??
```

Пробовал

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable AS T1
LEFT JOIN MyTable AS T2 ON T1.A = T2.B AND T1.B = T2.A
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

но отбрасывается не все данные.
Или на sql такую задачу не решить? решать её на php?

Comment: Почему ID 6 в выборке, такие же AB есть в 4 записи ?

Comment: Почему комбинации `16  17/17 16`  и `17  14/14  17`являются не уникальными?

Comment: Изменил, ошибся (писал с примера большого - почистил для наглядности) ИД 1, 2, 4 ??

Comment: нужно точные input и output иначе будете ждать помощи не к тому, что пытаетесь решить. В итоге ответы будут согласно вопросу, а значит верными

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select least(`A`,`B`), greatest(`A`,`B`), min(`id`)
  from MyTable
  group by least(`A`,`B`), greatest(`A`,`B`)
```

Разворачиваем AB так что бы меньший был всегда первым, а больший вторым и группируем по этой связке.

Можно и через JOIN, как то так:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM MyTable AS t1
  LEFT JOIN MyTable AS t2
    ON t2.id < t1.id
   AND (   (t1.`A` = t2.`B` AND t1.`B` = t2.`A`)
        OR (t1.`A` = t2.`A` AND t1.`B` = t2.`B`)
       )
 WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Спасибо, результирующая таблица правильная. Только помогите закончить запрос,  мне надо выбрать все записи с этими ИД,т..е.       SELECT * from rounds WHERE id IN  (select least(members_id, opponent_members), greatest(members_id, opponent_members), min(`id`)
  from rounds
  group by least(members_id, opponent_members), greatest(members_id, opponent_members)) AND turnirs_id = 1

Comment: @АлексейК Если используете IN то внутри выбирайте только 1 колонку т.е. `... IN(select min(id) from ...)` правда доп условие отфильтрует часть записей с минимальным id, так ли вам надо сами смотрите, возможно подобные условия нужны и внутри ..

Comment: Большое спасибо, решил вопрос без php обработки массива.