# Составить SQL запрос получить список диалогов

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Делаю чат.
В базе есть следующая структура:

```
Сущность Chat
id
text_message
id_user_from
id_user_to
```

Необходимо получить список диалогов (то есть все неповторяющиеся записи одновременно `id_user_from` и `id_user_to`). Возможно как-то это сделать средствами *SQL*?

Извиняюсь, вопрос может быть тупой, но я не особо силен в *SQL*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот верхняя таблица это полный список сообщений в диалоге
А нижняя это то что я хочу получить

То есть все НЕПОВТОРЯЮЩИЕСЯ комбинации id_user_from !И! id_user_to

Comment: Средствами SQL можно сделать выборку любой сложности. Особенно если задача четко сформулирована. По вашему вопросу к сожалению можно догадываться только в общих чертах. Может вам нужто что то типа этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676395/ а может обычный distinct ...

Comment: Почему в результате именно "Да, привет", а не "Привет, Марин" текст какого сообщения должен быть в результате ?

Comment: @Mike, ну вот с аналогией с мессенджерами. Там строится список диалогов вне зависимости от того Я ОТОСЛАЛ сообщение или  МНЕ ОТОСЛАЛИ сообщение(показывается последнее).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_user_from, id_user_to FROM Chat
```

Или так:

```
SELECT id_user_from, id_user_to FROM Chat
GROUP BY id_user_from, id_user_to
```

Comment: не подходит, нужно как-то одновременно distinct user_from и distinct user_to

Comment: Попробуйте вариант с `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Алексей пожалуйста, приведите в вопросе пример входных данных и что необходимо получить на выходе, иначе не ясно что именно вам надо

Comment: @Mike, кажется нашел решение в той ссылке которую вы скинули, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решение было найдено:

```
      SELECT * FROM Chat WHERE id IN ( SELECT max(id) as id FROM (SELECT id,
     id_user_from, id_user_to FROM Chat WHERE id_user_from =17 UNION ALL SELECT 
id, id_user_to, id_user_from FROM Chat WHERE id_user_to =17) t GROUP BY 
id_user_from, id_user_to ) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Запрос не из легких, но выводит даже в нужной последовательности

Comment: Это еще раз подтверждает, что надо более четко описывать задачу, в вашем вопросе ни слова ни сказано, что надо сделать выборку по определенному пользователю, а не по любым. И кстати в таком случае по той ссылке https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658939/ прямо ваш вопрос. а ответ отличается только тем, что при получении последнего сообщения надо брать не date, а `lpad(id,20,'0')`

Comment: @Mike , в любом случае спасибо за наводку)