# Вывести логины тех, с кем общался в чате

Tags: php, sql

Есть таблица msgs

```
id from_id to_id msg
1  5       6     msg1
2  6       5     msg2
3  7       5     msg3
4  5       6     msg4
```

и users

```
id login
5  user5
6  user6
7  user7
```

Пользователь №5 отправил смску пользователю №6, а потом №6 отправил смску №5,
если я сижу из под юзера №5, как мне вывести список тех, с кем общался, без повторений?

То есть я (юзер5) общался с:

юзер6

юзер7

Пробую так:

```
SELECT msg.id FROM msgs msg WHERE msg.from_id = 5 OR msg.to_id = 5;
```

Но выводит все полностью записи, 4шт.

А если группировать их по from_id или to_id - то получится так, что с другими юзерами не покажет...

Comment: "_То есть я (юзер5) общался с: юзер6 юзер7_" - верно, поэтому и выводит идентификаторы всех четырех сообщений. Может вам нужно выбирать не `msg.id` а ID пользователя? ;)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676395/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2/676404#676404

Comment: У вас в данных вроде users5 везде есть, вот и выводит

Comment: Помог этот вариант
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676395/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2/676404#676404

Answer (score 0):

А почему Вы указываете `msg.id`, если Вам нужен список пользователей, а не сообщений?

Правильный запрос выглядит так:

```
SELECT from_id FROM msgs WHERE to_id = 5
UNION
SELECT to_id FROM msgs WHERE from_id = 5;
```