# MYSQL Как сделать выборку по уникальному сочетанию двух полей?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Есть таблица в которой поля sender_id, receiver_id, text, timestamp_sent.

---

Нужно достать последнее сообщение по каждому из диалогов.
То есть достать одно сообщение по уникальному сочетанию sender_id и receiver_id 
С сортировкой по timestamp_sent desc.

---

DISTINCT я так понял работает сразу по всем полям. В том числе и text. А текст каждый раз разный. 
Как тут быть?:(

---

Нашел только вот такое решение, если есть идеи как сделать лучше, буду рад:)
Т.к. это не очень элегантно.

---

+ выборка должна быть по диалогам конкретного пользователя. по id. 
Пользователь может быть как в sender так и в receiver

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT text from message 
    WHERE sender_id=mess.sender_id AND receiver_id=mess.receiver_id
    ORDER BY  timestamp_sent DESC LIMIT 1
) AS txt, mess.sender_id, mess.receiver_id
FROM
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT sender_id, receiver_id
    from message 
    WHERE sender_id=1
    OR receiver_id=1
) AS mess
```

Comment: Можно что нибудь собрать из этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658939/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-sql-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/658954#658954 и этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676395/#676404

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sender_id, receiver_id, text, timestamp_sent 
FROM your_table AS outer_data 
WHERE (sender_id = ? OR receiver_id = ?) AND id = 
    (SELECT id 
    FROM your_table AS inner_data 
    WHERE outer_data.sender_id = inner_data.sender_id AND outer_data.receiver_id = inner_data.receiver_id 
    ORDER BY timestamp_sent DESC 
    LIMIT 1)
```

your_table - таблица. Надеюсь, **id**  в ней есть. 
Попробуйте выполнить и рассказать о результатах.
"id IN" как-нибудь оптимизируем позже

Вместо "?" поставить искомого собеседника (2 шт.).

Comment: Работает только сорри я не уточнил в условии, что диалоги должны быть по определенному пользователю который может быть как в sender так и в receiver

Comment: И id in не работает. Просто id =  нужно.
Т.к. limit нельзя юзать в in

Comment: Про условие не понял: нужно, чтобы sender_id или receiver_id равнялись какому-то изначально известному значению?

Comment: Фактически да. Это поиск диалогов с конкретным пользователем

Comment: Поправил и дополнил.