# SQL Обратная комбинация distinct

Tags: mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Как сделать так что бы при использовании distinct или может другим способом 
пары типа 10\20 и 20\10 считались одинаковыми? И не дублировались в запросе?

Comment: *пары типа 10\20 и 20\10* Они что, в текстовом поле хранятся в таком виде?

Comment: Не, имею ввиду два поля к примеру 
field1 и field2 
Если при select будут строки типа 
field1 = 10  и field2 = 20 
-------------------------------
field1 = 20 и field2 = 10 
То должно вернуть один из этих вариантов

Comment: @BrigelTolino Внимательнее читайте предлагаемые ссылки в комментариях. В вашем прошлом вопросе я вам давал ссылку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676395/#676404 за час до того как вы задали данный вопрос. И там в ответах ровно то же самое, что и в принятом вами ответе на этот вопрос. только написано более коротко least/greatest вместо if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в SELECT секции можно сравнивать значения

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(field1 >= field2, field2, field1) as field1, IF(field1 >= field2, field1, field2) as field2
FROM table;
```

Получается, что мы сортируем поля по их значениям, чтобы меньшие значения шли в 1 колонке, большие в второй. Тогда DISTINCT сработает как вам надо.

Comment: Блин, очень крутая идея, спасибо огромное) Все правильно работает)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(field1, field2), GREATEST(field1, field2)
```

Но помните, что и этот вариант, и вариант @**Skywave** - это фуллскан.

Comment: вот это важный момент. Для разовой работы в самый раз, но выкладывать в прод такой код я бы не стал. 1) правильно - фуллскан 2) Явное лучше, чем неявное (с) уж приятней читать в коде группировку по филду с понятным названием, чем непонятно что в селекте.

Comment: Окей, понял, а как это сделать без фуллскана? 
Ибо тут полная задача и ее решение, без учета вопроса тут.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702920/mysql-Как-сделать-выборку-по-уникальному-сочетанию-двух-полей/702923#702923

Comment: *как это сделать без фуллскана?* Получить симметричные данные со всеми отборами в подзапросах, объединённых UNION ALL, а уже на полученной компактной выборке применять этот фортель.