# Получить уникальные строки, где значения ячеек могут чередоваться

Tags: sql

Имеем таблицу

```
Москва    | Ленинград
Воронеж   | Сингапур
Ленинград | Москва
Сингапур  | Воронеж
Астана    | Киров
```

Необходимо получить

```
Москва    | Ленинград
Воронеж   | Сингапур
Астана    | Киров
```

Спасибо

Comment: По какому принципу у вас получиась результирующая таблица?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выборка не повторяющихся значений из одной таблицы чередующихся столбцов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676395/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Таблица была дана.